# Change Datatables jquery Header & Footer Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am building Database table using the following code:

```
<script>
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(document).ready(function()
        {
            j$('.reporstDT').dataTable(
            {
                'bJQueryUI': true,
                'bFilter': false,
                "bLengthChange": false
            });
        } );
</script>
```

and then I am calling the above script using  tag & adding Class="reporstDT" to my HTML5 table.
The problem is that the width of the generated table doesn't match my html table, as a result of this I get the following result:
http://www.imagebam.com/image/0e8fdb322413745

Can I configure the datatables header width and footer width properly without change their css styling?

Comment: I think the problem is with your table styling. You want your header and footer be same width as the content?

Comment: can you show us the html & css fiddle, i think you need to put the datatable in a div with limited width.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the column widths in the creation of the datatable, they are indexed left to right. This should override any setting in the css for the header and footer and pull them into line with the column width set here:

```
j$('.reporstDT').dataTable(
  {"bAutoWidth": false , 
    aoColumns : [
       { "sWidth": "25%"},
       { "sWidth": "25%"},
       { "sWidth": "25%"},
       { "sWidth": "25%"}
     ]
 });
```